# How to get travis to fail if tests do not have enough coverage for python

Tags: python, code-coverage, travis-ci

I it possible to have travis fail if my test don't have enough coverage, say < 90% for example.

Normally I run my tests with the following travis config entry.

```
script:
 - coverage run --source="mytestmodule" setup.py test
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to this [link](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.5/cmd.html#reporting), if you add the `--fail-under` switch to the coverage `report` command, it will exit with a non-zero exit code (which travis will see as a failure) if the code coverage is below the given percentage.

That would make the script section of your `.travis.yml` file look like:

```
script
 - coverage run --source="mytestmodule" setup.py test
 - coverage report --fail-under=80
```

Of course you could replace 80 with whatever percentage you'd like.

Comment: How do we add `--fail-under` for branch coverage?

Comment: @venkat The [documentation](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.0/config.html#report) doesn't list any sort of failure option for branch coverage. Perhaps you could output the report as JSON and do some sort of parsing yourself.

Comment: The link is dead.