# Make Travis fail if the coverage % is not above a threshold (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, travis-ci

How can I make Travis CI build fail if my coverage report is not 100%?
My .travis.yaml looks like this:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
   - 2.2.4
install: bundle install
script:
  - rspec spec/features/*
  - coverage report --fail-under=100
```

But this is coming out with this error in Travis: 
   The command "coverage report --fail-under=100" exited with 127.

Comment: looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33965755/how-to-get-travis-to-fail-if-tests-do-not-have-enough-coverage-for-python i think you may need to run the coverage using `coverage run` before you can use coverage report

Comment: @KimmoLehto this is a rails app, so I am not sure if I can run that. I am using a gem called simplecov which is basically runing the coverage for me and reporting it when the `rspec` command is finished.

Comment: coverage is maybe a python command. you may need a script that parses your coverage/index.html and returns 1 unless coverage = 100. Example: `grep "covered_percent" coverage/index.html | cut -d'>' -f3 | cut -d'.' -f1 | fgrep 100 || exit 1`

Comment: ok, so how would that script look like? @KimmoLehto

Comment: Found a better solution, in answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SimpleCov README](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov#customizing-exit-behaviour) describes exit behavior.

You can make simplecov fail the rspec test run if the coverage is below a set value.

Put this to spec helper right before simplecov is started:

```
SimpleCov.minimum_coverage 100
```

After that you can remove the coverage script line from .travis.yml

Comment: @kimmo.lehto: great idea. Will that make Travis fail though?

Comment: Yes. The rspec test run will exit with non zero exit code. If exit code == 0 travis will say success, if something else it will say failure.

Comment: @Vlad nice. then you should mark my answer as the answer :)